# Can’t change phone time - set automatic time grayed out

Tags: iphone, ios, time, timezone

Currently traveling in Europe on a cruise with intermittent cell coverage. Having to change my phone and watch time frequently. Seems to be impossible to do manually. The set time toggle is locked in automatic.

[image]

Any idea what I am missing here?  Tried disabling location services for time zone.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few reasons as to why this might be disabled.

1. Do you have an Exchange account connected to the phone? There might be a policy connected to it, disabling the option to change the timezone.
2. If you look in Settings > Privacy > Location Services > System Services (in the bottom), is the option "Setting Time Zone" disabled?
3. If you have Screen Time enabled with a pass code, that might also disable the option to change time zone. Try to disable Screen Time, restart, and then try again.

Hope that solves it for you.

Comment: Yes to Exchange but no policy. Tried both location services settings. No screen time.

Comment: @DanTappin, could you try removing the Exchange account, restarting the phone, and then try again?

Comment: Is it possible the phone number/sim provider has set this?